# "PrismaClientInitializationError" Can not connect to database

Tags: node.js, backend

I am trying to deploy my NodeJS app to Microsoft azure app services and is connected to database using Prisma.

The deployment was successful, but whenever I access an API route with a connection to the database, I get the following error as a response:

{"status":500,"message":"Internal Server Error-DB","error":{"name":"PrismaClientInitializationError","clientVersion":"5.1.1"}}

My database string looks like this: "sqlserver://host;db;user;password;

Can anyone guide me if I need to redefine my database string with any other parameter or something else?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.